Is there a way in rmarkdown html to make results hideable/showable similar to what code_folding does for echo?
When rendering html in rmarkdown, there's the handy option of making your code chunk echos foldable through the YAML header:
output:
  html_document:
    code_folding: "hide"

With echo = TRUE this allows your HTML document to have handy "show" buttons for each code chunk that toggle them on or off:
#this is my echo chunk

If I knit the above two chunks, my echo chunk can be toggled on or off. Lovely. But how do I do the equivalent for printed results, e.g. the printed output summary of a model?
summary(lm(Sepal.Length ~ Sepal.Width, data = iris))

The code block still toggles, of course, but the printed results will show unless 'results=hide' is set, which is not what I want. I want the end user to be able to hide and unhide the results at their leisure, like they would the code block.
Can this be done at any level? YAML? Code chunk? Adhoc?

you might want to try something like this.
